# Bootstrap: Twitter Bootstrap Modal not hidden when page loaded

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I copied the code exactly the same from the example given:

```
<-- Button to trigger modal -->
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<-- Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
<h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<p>One fine body…</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</div>
</div>
```

from

```
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals
```

When the page first loaded up, the modal showed up immediately. I do not have the javascript to trigger it. The live demo on their site does not behave like this. Anything missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the `hide` class to your modal.

**Update** In B3, the modals have been completely revamped. You shouldn't need this class.

If it still shows, insure you're using the correct syntax in your HTML. It should hide by default.

Comment: That works. Thanks. Are they suppose to update their documentation? The example they give and the live demo behave differently.

Comment: Late to the game, but wanted to input. Syntax was my issue. In the first div, I had class="modal-fade" instead of class="modal fade". The other classes have the -, so I guess I just threw it in there.